# Adding a product programatically to wordpress woocommerce website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm quite new in wordpress and woocommerce plugin and I would like to create an app that would add products programatically to a website using this plugin.
I thought about writing directly into the database in the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables. However, I've read about some php woocommerce functions, but I know nothing about this and where to write the php code.

Is the solution I provided is clean enough?
Otherwise how could I use the php functions provided by woocommerce?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use the [REST API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product)?

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking Thanks for your answer. How could i use the php library? I don't find any link to download it

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php

Comment: i'll try that thanks